# width: 100%; height: auto dont work properly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Wordpress to build a website. I have set images as slider with bootstrap. My css codes are:

```
min-width: 100%;
height: auto;
object-fit: contain;
overflow: hidden;
```

But it stretches itself unexpectedly. It shows it's height much more bigger than it supposed to be. It decreases its resolution also.

My index.php code is:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide">
                    <!-- Indicators -->
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators hidden-xs">
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    </ol>

                    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <?php $minipost = new WP_Query(array(
                            'post_type' => 'cover-slider',
                            'posts_per_page' => 3
                        ));
                        $i = 1;
                        ?>

                    <?php while($minipost->have_posts()): $minipost->the_post();?>
                        <div class="item<?php if ($i == 1) echo ' active'; ?>">

                                <?php the_post_thumbnail(array('thumbnail', 'class' => ' img-responsive img-full'));?>

                        </div>  
                    <?php $i++; ?>
                    <?php endwhile;?>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Controls -->
                    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="icon-prev"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="icon-next"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
```

The original image is

[image]

But after using as a slider it shows....

[image]

Comment: Is that the only CSS you have? Any more CSS files you have included?

Comment: Yes I have bootstrap.min.css and style.css. But style.css doesn't contain any code. I just used it only for theme purpose. The name of my stylesheet file is business-casual.css. Its actually a ready made HTML Template. @BrandonZ

Comment: Does it work as HTML webpage? If it does then you may not be including your business-casual.css properly.

Comment: Show us some PHP that you use to render the actual slider HTML.

Comment: use dev tools inspector to see what rules are applied to image and its wrapper

Comment: I have added index.php code with my Question. @Zlatev

Answer (score 2):

Changing your css `min-width: 100%` to `width: 100%` should be working as min-width will force the image to scale back to it's original size rather than it's available spaces.

**My answer is based on prediction due to lack of sample code.**

Answer (score 0):

Your `the_post_thumbnail()` arguments are off. Check out the syntax [`the_post_thumbnail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/) in the refs. To get your attachments at full size use

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array('class' => ' img-responsive img-full')); ?>
```

As first argument we pass the actual image size we want to display. Second argument are the image attributes.